# SharePoint online Apps To local Sharepoint Server Apps

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, office-365

I am a beginner in SharePoint and I already create an Auto hosted SharePoint app with VS 2013 and deploy it and install it successfully in Office 365 site Online.

I wanna know if there is a possibility to get my application in my local SharePoint Server to work with it locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, auto-hosted apps are only available on Office 365, since Azure auto-hosting is only available to apps deployed to SharePoint Online. You need to use a provider-hosted or SharePoint-hosted app model to be able to use it on-premise.

More about the hosting alternatives here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887.aspx#Autohosted

Comment: Thanks Robert for Your Answer

But I didn't ask if I can create an auto Hosted app In local server. Or even Upload it on my local server.

My question is after creating and installing the application in Office 365 Online, I want to use it in my local server Sharepoint, 
So I ask if there is a way to download the app from office 365 Online to my Local Sharepoint Server.

Comment: Well the answer is no! You need to install the app on the server, and you can't because Auto-Hosted Apps can only be installed and hence used in Office 365

Comment: I really had doubt in that , Thx Anyway :)